# Object values only appending to one select option and stops on the next one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have data of this sort. I have arrays saved in an object, and am trying to append the options from my object into the select option. It is displaying correctly in the first select option, but not displaying on the second. The following is my code.

```
<script>
var stateObject = {
    "Nairobi": {
      "Delhi": ["new Delhi", "North\/Delhi"],
      "Kerala": ["Thiruvananthapuram", "Palakkad"],
      "Goa": ["North Goa", "South Goa"],
    },
    "Australia": {
      "South Australia": ["Dunstan", "Mitchell"],
      "Victoria": ["Altona", "Euroa"]
    }, "Canada": {
      "Alberta": ["Acadia", "Bighorn"],
      "Columbia": ["Washington", ""]
    },
  }

window.onload = function () {
    var countySel = document.getElementById("countySel"),
    stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel"),
    districtSel = document.getElementById("districtSel");
    for (var country in stateObject) {
      countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(country, country);
    }
    countySel.onchange = function () {
      stateSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
      districtSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
      if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done
      for (var state in stateObject[this.value]) {
        stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
      }
    }
    countySel.onchange(); // reset in case page is reloaded
    stateSel.onchange = function () {
      districtSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
      if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done
      var district = stateObject[countySel.value][this.value];
      for (var i = 0; i < district.length; i++) {
        districtSel.options[districtSel.options.length] = new Option(district[i], district[i]);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I append in select, it only applies in one select option, the other is not working. Any idea on how the second one can be affected.

```
    //appending to this option
    <select name="county" id="countySel" class="form-control" required>
      <option value = "" selected="selected" class="form-control">--Select--</option>
    </select>

    //not appending to this option
    <select name="county" id="countySel" class="form-control" required>
      <option value = "" selected="selected" class="form-control">--Select--</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: It appears you have two `<select>` - both with the same ID `id="countySel"` - IDs must be unique.  `document.getElementById("countySel")` will only get the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have 2 or more elements with the same I'd on the same page...

That is 2 countrySel IDs; so only 1 element will end up usable in js. Use different IDs...